# Remove custom installed build task on tfs

Tags: c#, tfs

I have installed few custom build tasks on TFS:
[image]

I have new version of same task, but can't update:
[image]

How do I uninstall custom build task from tfs or how to update existing with new version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're saying TFS so I will assume you're using TFS2015 U2 or greater. It also assumes you're using basic authentication with your TFS API instances.

If you **DON'T** have Basic auth, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34265473/how-to-get-pat-from-on-premise-tfs2015) for a trick using Fiddler.

You can attempt to remove the task by using the [tfs-cli](https://github.com/Microsoft/tfs-cli) and using the commands found under the [Build Tasks](https://github.com/Microsoft/tfs-cli/blob/master/docs/buildtasks.md) page.

**Note: This requires you to install node.js**

Here is what that would look like:

```
tfx login --auth-type basic
TFS Cross Platform Command Line Interface v0.3.9
Copyright Microsoft Corporation
>Service URL: https://tfs:8080/
>Username: DOMAIN\USER
>Password:

tfx build tasks delete --task-id [guid from error message]
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to delete the old version. The error message says "...version '0.2.5' has already been uploaded...". Thus you only have to ensure that the new version has a higher version number. This can be done in the task.json of the module:

```
  "version": {
    "Major": "0",
    "Minor": "2",
    "Patch": "6"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to do it. If the task is custom, then it goes to the task group. Below are the steps

[image]

If you are planning to delete an extension task that you installed from the market place, then you need to do the following

[image]

[image]