# Hide some built-in build/release tasks in TFS

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

TFS 2017 u2. The task gallery for build/release definitions is crowded by tasks that are utterly irrelevant to our software shop. They're built-in, so removing the extension is not an option.

Any way to hide them?

Answer (score 3):

**CAVEAT** I discourage you: if you need to reinstall a Task, the process is non-trivial.

This has already been answered at [Remove custom installed build task on tfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38416501/remove-custom-installed-build-task-on-tfs)

The idea is to use `tfx build tasks delete`. You need the GUID of the task: a quick way to get it is to look at the `task.json` file in the https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks repository.

Comment: I second the caveat. You never know when you might need one of those "irrelevant" tasks.

Comment: That's why the question says "hide" instead of "delete".

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no way to hide the tasks. You could search the tasks you want to use, and I've submitted a UserVoice at website below, you can vote it:

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/33373423-hide-build-tasks