# How should I handle the deprecated tasks in TFS/VSTS?

Tags: tfs

There are always been some deprecated extensions/tasks in the build task list.

Microsoft only add a tag with this kind of task, did it just mean :" **we recommend that you do not use this task; it's deprecated**"

It's beyond me, if the task is deprecated, why Microsoft not simply move it?

I have noticed some task have different version, will this deprecated task version updated in the feature?

Could I directly deleted this annoying deprecated task?

Comment: Things are depreciated to give you advance warning of their eventual removal. If they removed them immediately it would break peoples' builds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We’re not planning **any feature updates, bug fixes, or support** for the deprecated features.

Take a look at this:

> We consider that **a certain task is deprecated only when the latest
>   version of that task is marked as deprecated.**
>
> When the user searches for deprecated tasks, we push these tasks to
>   the end and group them under a collapsible section that's collapsed by
>   default.
>
> If a definition is already using a deprecated task, we would show a
>   deprecated task badge on the task so that it's clear to the user that
>   the task is deprecated and hence is not currently being maintained,
>   there by encouraging them to make a switch to the replacement.
>
> It is recommended to mention in the task description about **the new
>   task that is going to replace the deprecated task.**
>
> *[Source Link: Deprecated Tasks](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/deprecatedtasks.md#deprecated-tasks)*

---

*As for how long before it goes from deprecated to being removed?*

Even though some task has been deprecated, but it will be available for a while.

> We understand that moving existing definitions over will take some
>   time for our customers. As such, we have not determined a date for the
>   removal. We encourage that new definitions be created with new task
>   and also move existing definitions over as soon as it is possible for
>   you.

For delete a task, already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48853663/5391065). Take care of this,  if you need to reinstall a Task, the process is **non-trivial**.